# Rails sort_by on Array throwing ArgumentError because of nil values - shouldn't it just sort depending on database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am sorting an Array in Rails 4 using sort_by:

```
sort_column = 'experience_in_months'
@userstoshow=@userstoshow.sort_by(&:"#{sort_column}")
```

This throws an error

> An ArgumentError occurred in *SNIP*:
>
> comparison of Fixnum with nil failed

This is a strange problem because I remember reading about this earlier. It was supposed to put the nil values first or last based on the database used. I am using PostGreSQL.

I remember this working quite flawlessly a few days ago - it just put nil values at the top in my table.

It isn't a difficult problem to solve - I can take out the nil values, sort the rest and then add back the nil enteries. But I would like to be clear if this is a random behaviour or if it is as expected.

Comment: The code above as-is has nothing to do with databases at all. What's inside `@userstoshow`? An `ActiveRecord::Relation`?

Comment: True, I confused it with order_by which I was earlier using. But now I am using sort_by because @usertoshow is an array.

Comment: @arunt, what does your array hold? objects of type User?

Comment: Yes. I believe the others have mentioned the problem. I was wrong about the suspected wrong behavior too. Earlier, I was using order which handles nil values, but I switched to sort_by since @userstoshow is now an array.


Thanks for the help. I don't know how I overlooked this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is expected behavior

#### Database ordering only applies in database queries

Once the data is out of the database, Ruby has full control and ruling over ordering rules. **Databases' rules no longer apply** because arrays are used everywhere and no gems expect them to be broken in this way.

Taking advantage of the fact that `nil.to_i` is `0`, you can use the following:

```
attribute_proc = sort_column.to_sym.to_proc
@userstoshow = @userstoshow.sort_by { |x| attribute_proc.call(x).to_i }
```

...and you're replacing the value in-place, so you can use `sort_by!`, not `sort_by`:

```
attribute_proc = sort_column.to_sym.to_proc
@userstoshow.sort_by! { |x| attribute_proc.call(x).to_i }
```

Looks kinda intimidating. That's because you're not using a fixed attribute name. Otherwise, it'd be:

```
@userstoshow.sort_by! { |x| x.experience_in_months.to_i }
```

Comment: Thanks, you diagnosed the problem correctly. I don't know how I overlooked that I changed from 'order' to  'sort_by'! I still have one small problem. This will work for attributes, but what if I want to sort by a derived value? For example, my table column is 'Age' and not 'DOB'. I am trying to compress the code so that one block of code can handle all the sorting instead of 'if-else' blocks that check whether it is a method or attribute. But if you think that it will be a better idea to just go with the 'if-else', then I will do that.

EDIT: there is a function `age` for Users.

Comment: @arunt pass a block as an argument to your method and specify the comparatee at call site. That will work.

Answer (score 2):

@arunt, I am guessing that you have in `@userstoshow` objects of type `User` or something as such.

Now when you use *Ruby*'s `sort_by` it enumerates over the collection and tries to `a <=> b`, here is an equivalent code snippet.

```
@userstoshow = @userstoshow.sort_by do |a, b|
  a.experience_in_months <=> b.experience_in_months
end
```

Now Ruby doesn't know how to compare a Fixnum to a NilClass, here is a similar case

```
[1, 2, 3, nil].sort => ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with nil failed
```

So the problem is that your `User` object is returning `nil` for some of it's object rather than a Fixnum value.

So you can either change your `sort_by` to include a code block or fix your User object to return a default value which is not nil.

Comment: Except it's not `sort_by`, but just `sort` in your example: `sort_by` accepts a block that returns the property being sorted, when `sort` accepts a comparator-block.